# Why Apache CXF?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-ws, cxf

I am a new to Java EE Services. In my project they will be using JAX-WS with Apache CXF. I want to know what is Apache CXF? I can use plain JAX-WS to create Web Services. Why should I use Apache CXF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) is just one of the implementations of [JAX-WS API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services). There are other implementations, such as [JAX-WS RI](http://jax-ws.java.net/) (reference implementation) that is included in Java and part of Metro framework (which includes some other things also, like WSIT).

Your question is - what are the reasons to choose Apache CXF? There are plenty of them, for example:

1. support for RESTful services (becoming more and more popular)
2. easy integration with Spring (if that matters to you)
3. WS-* support (i.e., support for many important WS-specifications like WS-Security)
4. maturity (thanks @sourcedelica)

References:

- [Why CXF?](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/why-cxf.html)

Comment: Agree, forgot to mention that.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you please tell me what is Reference implementation and What is Metro framework?

Comment: @Sandeep JAX-WS RI (reference implementation) is, let's call it, "official" implementation of JAX-WS API. In other words, it covers all parts of appropriate specification (that is, JSR 224). Furthermore, JAX-WS is a core of Metro Web service framework. Metro framework is centered around interoperability with other frameworks, especially with Windows Communication Foundation, that is why Metro includes WSIT (Web Services Interoperability Technologies). That means, at least in theory, that Metro-built Web service can normally communicate with .NET-built Web service client and vice versa.